# In Swift - Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift, delegates, swift-protocols

```
func resetInfoPopUp() {
    if let resetInfo = self.viewModel.getResetInfo()
    {
        self.presentNotificationWithoutActionPopUpDelegate(title: resetInfo.title,
                                                   message: resetInfo.description,
                                                   infoImage: resetInfo.imageFileName,
                                                   delegate: self)
    }
}
```

Im getting this error **"Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"**

Here is the function which I'm calling from ViewController class.

```
func presentNotificationWithoutActionPopUpDelegate(title: NSAttributedString, 
                                                   message: NSAttributedString, 
                                                   infoImage: UIImage? = nil, 
                                                   delegate: PopUpActionDelegate? = nil) {

    let notificationViewController = NotificationViewWithoutActionViewController(title: title, 
     message: message, infoImage: infoImage)
 
    notificationViewController.gotItActionDelegate = delegate

    self.present(notificationViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

`NotificationViewWithoutActionViewController` is a viewcontroller class where the popup function is declared.

```
@IBAction func acknowledgeAction() {
    gotItActionDelegate?.gotItButtonAction()
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

`gotItButtonAction` is func defined in protocol.

[Check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy4AK.png)

```
 struct ResetInfo
  {
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var imageFileName: UIImage
  }
```

Comment: What does `self.viewModel.getResetInfo` return?

Comment: it return the data to be shown on popup. which has title, desc & image.

Comment: my issue is with respect to delegate, how should I confirm it? I will be using this gotItButtonAction protocol in some other class to get notified when user clicks on popup action.

Comment: Please show the declaration of the type that `self.viewModel.getResetInfo` returns.

Comment: Conform `self` to `PopUpActionDelegate`?

Comment: Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: yes self conform to **PopUpActionDelegate**

Comment: Show us your return object implementation of `viewModel.getResetInfo()`

Comment: @TomasJablonskis check I have added the code.

Comment: The `ResetInfo` implementation would help aswell.

Comment: @TomasJablonskis can you tell me what I have been missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are passing wrong parameters to `presentNotificationWithoutActionPopUpDelegate` function. `String` is not the same as `NSAttributedString`.

---

To fix this issue you could do something like this:

```
// Extension for convenient String conversion to NSAttributedString
extension String {
    var attributed: NSAttributedString {
        NSAttributedString(string: self)
    }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
let info = ResetInfo(...)
presentNotificationWithoutActionPopUpDelegate(
    title: info.title.attributed,
    message: info.description.attributed,
    ...
)
```